# Trajectory on Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot trajectories on Matlab. I have created the vector field plot using the following code and I would like to add trajectories. Please help! Also if there's a tutorial online somewhere please send it my way

```
syms v(t) w(t)
eqn1 = 0 == v(t)-(v(t)^3*(1/3))-w(t)+1
eqn2 = 0 == .1*(v(t)+.7-.7*w(t))
[v,w]=meshgrid(-5:.5:5,-5:.5:5)
[eqn1,eqn2]=meshgrid(-5:.5:5,-5:.5:5)
quiver(v,w,eqn1,eqn2)
```

Comment: I've never found an interesting MatLab online tutorial, either. However, if you don't mind long, dry tutorials there are TONS of useful tutorials on YouTube(i.e. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDWB6KZ1oWo&list=PLG4WfqoDFRvkPdujlErCsGjjvKTfOyF0A). If you find an interesting one, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The m_map package can be somehow interesting

https://www.eoas.ubc.ca/~rich/map.html

try to get a look to m_quiver, I used it many times to plot trajectories of Lagrangian floats